# Groovy installation pcl fail

Tags: pcl, ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been through about a million groovy installation problems (source install on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit). This one, in particular, stumped me because I don't exactly know what's going on between the build_isolated and install_isolated directories, or how/where built libraries are installed so packages dependent on them (in the course of the install) can find them. Here's the error with the tail end of a successful package build:

```
 Processing plain cmake package: 'pcl'
==> Building with env: '/home/sean/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/sean/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/sean/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'
[  1%] Built target pcl_pcd_convert_NaN_nan
[  1%] Built target pcl_io_ply
[  2%] Built target pcl_octree
[  2%] Built target pcl_ply2obj
[  3%] Built target pcl_ply2ply
[  3%] Built target pcl_ply2raw
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_common.so
[  4%] Built target pcl_plyheader
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsensor_msgs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lroscpp_serialization
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrosconsole
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrostime
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_common.so.1.6.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

 /home/sean/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54690/groovy-installation-pcl-fail/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See
http://answers.ros.org/question/53401/error-when-compiling-pcl-for-ros-groovy-install-from-source-on-ubuntu-12041/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2013-02-08**:
This did fix the above error, so it's the correct answer, but it left me with another error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcl_visualization. Just an FYI for anyone else that finds this post.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2013-02-08**:
This post makes sense, but I can't find exactly where pcl_visualization is not being installed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874684/compiling-pcl-for-use-with-opencv

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2013-02-08**:
Another FYI, I circumvented the new error by excluding the particular example class that was breaking the build.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-08**:
I would prefer you to comment on the other question, because that's where I'll send all others with the same problem.